# How can I increase the google drive quota limit?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, video-streaming, html5-video

So I have a HTML5 video player that plays a video from Google Drive. The video is more than 100MB in size, so I created a Google Drive API key and included it in the code for the video. However, I can only play about five videos until my quota runs out. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a more efficient way to play the video, without constantly running out of my quota? This is the error I'm getting:

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "downloadQuotaExceeded", "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded." } }

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    window.parent.postMessage("ready", "*");
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var source = document.getElementById('source');
        source.src = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + event.data.id + "?key=<APIKEY>&alt=media"
        video.appendChild(source)
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            video.currentTime = event.data.playHead;
        });
    }
  }
</script>
<video id="video" width="100%" height: auto controls style="display:block; margin:0 auto;">
  <source id='source' src="" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Is uploading the video to Youtube and embedding the video an option for you?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact error message we need to have an idea which quota you think you are exceeding.

Answer (score 2):

How to increase the google drive quota:

1. go to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Left hand side select Library search for google drive api
3. Click manage (blue button)
4. Left hand menu select quotas
5. Click the pencil icon to increase the quota.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response. However, I already have the maximum amount in there. Is there maybe another way, or am I just out of luck here?

Comment: There should be a link where you can apply for an extension.   TBH i was not aware that there was any download quota like this.   Are you sure its a quota error you are getting?

Comment: So the error I'm getting is a 403. This JSON comes with it: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "downloadQuotaExceeded",
    "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
 }
}

Comment: This error is not related to Google Drive quota listed in the developer console.  The quota  was exceeded only on this specific file, which means this file has been downloaded too many times.  Google has many undocumented quotas for APIs, downloadQuotaExceeded is one of them.    Any solution to this problem?

Comment: As far as i know the downloadQuotaExceeded limit is 50 per day by i have only seen it on videos and there is no way around that.

Comment: It says `apply for higher quota` : `Request more drive quota
By default Drive provides a courtesy queries per day and per second quota. If you'd like to request more, please fill out this form. We'll contact you if we have any additional questions. Please allow 2 weeks for these requests to get processed.`