# Can you use Google Drive to host images and other binary files?

Tags: google-drive-api, file-sharing

I am reading [this](https://www.labnol.org/google-drive-image-hosting-220515) which shows how to grab an image link from a Google Drive image, but is it a stable solution that will continue to work indefinitely, or is it an undocumented feature?

Similarly, I would like to host arbitrary files (sound files, video files, PDFs, etc.) on Google Drive, and be able to render or play them in my custom web app which I am building with JavaScript/Node.js. Can I directly load an image or sound or video file in the appropriate HTML tag (like `<audio src="googledrivepath.com/foo.mp3">`), and it will work? If so, how do I do it?

If not, is there not any way to directly access the raw link from a Google Drive upload? Maybe even I have to make a hack which fetches some HTML and then scrapes out the "internal" link, that would be a solution and good to know. But whatever is easiest is preferred. I would basically like to try and use Google Drive as an ad-hoc file storage/fetching solution for my web app, instead of AWS S3 because of the cost factor. Having the ease of use of using Google Drive will also be a bonus, for previewing and permissioning/removing the content if necessary, so there's that benefit as well.

Note, I can't just copy the link like say https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Q7lAZvhyacNlC_TWFyYkyBqjOnaQDf1/view?usp=sharing, because it loads the whole Google Drive app to show the image. If I use the chrome network inspector, I can find https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AJc5JmTFCEWlr0h7u3NUgLcG7umRuy12kdy_hsALUVRp287knYtEBDvg2FTAEYl3y06tUCYNaRf8GYk=w2880-h1526, which is what I want, but I don't know how to get that more easily or if it will remain stable.

Comment: While a link to an external resource might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. Please add directly in the question body the relevant parts of the referred article.

Comment: I don't think that Google Drive could be considered universally a reliable hosting for websites / web apps assets because there have been reports of files that have being blocked for having too many downloads. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/16856102/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61318947/1595451

Comment: If the volume of files and users is small (i.e. family vacations private album shared only with friends and family) Google Drive might be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, depending on what you are doing with it, you may get limited for too many downloads too frequently, however there are two approaches that work in my experience:

1. You can load a file via `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[file ID]`.  If the file is not accessible to anyone with the link, the user will need to be signed into Drive with an account with access for it to work.
2. Create a Google API project with the Google Drive API enabled, and use the API URL `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[file ID]?alt=media&key=[Google API key]`.

There is, of course, also the more “correct” approach of using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to retrieve files.